# Sencha Touch - DataView - Continous Loading

Tags: json, extjs, sencha-touch, dataview

I am new to sencha touch and trying to learn.  Build a small app that loads a JSON string from a file.  When I run my app on localhost, dataview displays properly, but when I run the same app from my shared hosting account, I get a "loading" graphic in an infinite loop and no data is displayed.  You can reproduce the "loading" graphic using this URL:
[Reproduce Error](http://sencha.mussanisoft.com/myapp/)

My .js code:

```
var buglist;
Ext.setup({
    tabletStartupScreen: 'tablet_startup.png',
    phoneStartupScreen: 'phone_startup.png',
    icon: 'icon.png',
    glossOnIcon: false,

    onReady: function () {
        Ext.regModel('bugs', {
            fields: ['bg_id', 'bg_short_desc', 'bg_reported_date']
        });

        var productsList = new Ext.DataView({
            store: new Ext.data.Store({
                model: 'bugs',
                proxy: {
                    type: 'ajax',
                    url: 'bugs.json',
                    reader: {
                        type: 'json',
                        root: 'd'
                    }
                },
                autoLoad: true
            }),
            tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
               '<tpl for=".">',
                    '<div class="item">',
                        '<p>{bg_id}</p>',
                        '<p>{bg_short_desc}</p>',
                    '</div>',
                '</tpl>'
            ),
            itemSelector: "div.item",
            fullscreen: true

        });
    }
});
```

My JSON string:

```
{"d":[{"bg_id":3,"bg_short_desc":"Reports - Efficiency - time from order to shipment","bg_reported_date":"\/Date(1261589913930)\/"},{"bg_id":5,"bg_short_desc":"Remove SKU 375906","bg_reported_date":"\/Date(1262195615067)\/"}]}
```

Please help.
Thanks
Sajjad

Answer (score 0):

The bg_reported_date, why are you wrapping it in Date()? Just use type: 'date' and dateFormat : 'U' in your field for bg_reported_date Model.

Have you looked at the reponse? Did it return? Error?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do I look into response? Can you share some code to do that?

Sajjad

Comment: Figured it out.  My web server was not able to handle MIME Type for JSON